# Showing text on a button above the image on the same button on Swift 3

Tags: swift, image, button, swift3, uibutton

I'm trying to show text of a button in Swift 3, when that same button has a png image of a circle. I want the text above the image, but the image is above the text.

Comment: you need to  show your code what are you trying? also if you share any image what are you trying to achieve ? that would be better for us to help you

Comment: you need to set image as background image in button

Comment: You can set custom `titleEdgeInsets` and `imageEdgeInsets`, but in my experience, it's *really* hard to get them just right.

Comment: I would imagine that without showing your code, you won't get very far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `Title Insets` and `Image insets` settings in Interface Builder:

[image]

And/Or set [`titleEdgeInsets`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624010-titleedgeinsets) and [`imageEdgeInsets`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624034-imageedgeinsets) properties of `UIButton` programmatically.